# Set first 50 row values of iris.data to Null values. Use numpy.nan

Tags: python, numpy

Set first 50 row values of iris.data to Null values. Use numpy.nan

Perform Imputation on 'iris.data' and save the transformed data in variable 'iris_imputed'.

Hint : use Imputer API, Replace numpy.NaN values with mean of corresponding data.
Print the mean of every column using the below command. print(iris_imputed.mean(axis=0))

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: How Set first 50 row values of iris.data to Null values. Use numpy.nan?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use array slicing to achieve your goal

**Code:**

```
iris_data[:50,:] = np.nan
```

**Explanation:**
Here iris_data is a Numpy array.
In the first part, you select all rows starting from 0th row to 50th row.
In the second part, you select all columns.

If the iris_data is a DataFrame instead you can use iloc function in the same way.

**Code:**

```
iris_data.iloc[:50,:] = np.nan
```